# Unable to select value from combo box. Require JS alternative

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a combo box in our project for which I had written XPATH. Though XPATH checker has been able to locate it properly while writing XPATH but when I ran the test it was not doing the operation of selecting the values. I tried multiple XPATHs but nothing seemed to work.

Here is the HTML design of it

```
   <select class="" style="margin-bottom:5px; width:150px; font-size:12px;"     name="statusDetail868">
   <option value="0">APPROVED</option>
   <option selected="selected" value="2">PENDING</option>
   <option value="3">REJECTED</option>
   </select>
```

I had tried following CssSelector

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("//select[name='statusDetail798']"))).selectByVisibleText("APPROVED");
```

didn't work out

I was thinking of including Javascript. I tried this

```
js.executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('').options[2].selected=true");
```

it was giving me error
"org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: document.getElementsByClassName(...).options is undefined"

What could be javascript for it as it does not have "ID" there is only class name?

Comment: May be it's just a typo in question, but name is 'statusDetail868', while xpath contains 'statusDetail798'. It obviously won't match using a different name

Comment: @Jk1 got your point. I didn't notice it. But can you tell me the JS equivalent for selecting a value from combo box especially when we don't have ID?

Comment: Well you've got things totally wrong here. Your CSS selector in your question is an XPath selector. So what is it that you are actually doing?

Answer (score 0):

As Arran said, "Your CSS selector in your question is an XPath selector", so how about actually using an XPath selector?

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[name='statusDetail798']/option[text()='APPROVED']")).click();`

Comment: I got it solved. I did not check that the statusDetail798 is dynamically getting changed. I wrote following xpath                       //td[@class='contact']/child::select[contains(@name,'statusDetail')]     Can you give the JS alternative for it

Comment: @crazynik I think you could still just add `/option[text()='APPROVED']` to the end of your xpath to select the option (with click()). I don't see why you need a JS alternative